# Check If Sitecore is a MVC installtion

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

Is there a easy way to find out if a `Sitecore` installation on the server includes `MVC`?
I am a total `Sitecore` beginner and have to migrate `ASP.NET Forms` to `MVC`.

Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if `Sitecore.MVC.config` is there in `App_Config\Include` folder.

Or open `http://.../sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` url. See if MVC settings are there.

E.g.:

```
<sitecore>
  <pipelines>
    <mvc.getRenderer>
```